# How to use a different version of ruby but with the same gemset?

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

On my computer, I run `ruby1.9.2-p290` with a `system` gemset. I want to keep testing out the edge version of Ruby in my development env, but I don't want to install all the gems again and keep mostly identical copies of the same gem files.

How could I switch to `ruby1.9.3-p325` using the same `system` gemset with rvm?

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
rvm gemset copy 1.9.2-p290@system 1.9.3@system
```

Comment: yes it does, but some gems are compiled against system / ruby and it's not fully safe to assume they will work correctly between 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 ... maybe if it would be 1.9.3-p125 - 1.9.3-p194 this would be possible, but in your situation, I would not bet on it. Also the gemset copy calls `gem pristine` on every copied gem to make sure it's ready to work with given ruby, in some cases gems will fail to compile and you will be notified which gems need manual rebuilding.